# Using cellfun for logical indexing

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell `data` containing one row and four column. What i am trying to do is to go through elements in first column and see if an year '2018' is seen in the first column of each cell. When i perform this code, it will only give me the indices containing '2018' in the fourth cell. Not all the cells. Any help will be appreciated.

```
time = cellfun(@x, contains(x,'2018'),data{ii}(:,1))
```

[image: This is the image of cell <code>data</code>]

Comment: please give an example dataset, it will be difficult to answer otherwise, the problem could lie in how the data is formatted.

Comment: It looks like your code is missing a closing parenthesis. What is `ii`? Is it `4`, by any chance? I agree, example data would be very helpful.

Comment: The image of the cell is added as the size is really large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a small data sample as part of an example which I hope will help you solve the problem.

```
%Create cell array of strings.
data = {["2018","date","2018";"stack","cell2018","fun"],["data","stackoverflow","2018";"array","variable","data2018"]}

%Search for substring 2018 in the first column of every cell.
time = cellfun(@(x) contains(x(:,1),'2018'),data,'UniformOutput',0)
```

The output of time is a logical cell array:

```
>>time 

{2×1 logical}    {2×1 logical}

>>time{1}

1
0

>>time{2}

0
0
```

For the first cell, the column contains `2018` and `stack`, therefore `1` and `0` are returned.

For the second cell, the column contains `data` and `array`, therefore `0` and `0` are returned.

If you wish to find the indexes from the logical array, you can use the [find](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function with outputs `[row,col]`.